# function to compute orthogonal projection matrix

Tags: webgl, fragment-shader

I was given a code of shaders (vertex and fragment) and my goal is to add some functionality into. But I'm having a trouble to understand some functions and Math inside. I have an image I want to project the texture of this image onto the cylinder. This is how I'm getting pixels from texture:

```
float hFOV=0.0789;      // orizontal field of view
float aspectRatio=1.5;  
float ax = tan(hFOV * M_PI);
float ay = ax / aspectRatio;
vec4 q1 = myW2N(ax,ay,1.,6.) * vec4(d, 1.); // ??    
vec2 p = q1.xy / q1.w;
p = 0.5 * (p + 1.0);
vec4 c = texture2D(foto, p);
```

But what makes me a headache is `myW2N()` function, I can't go through the idea inside and what the result means. Its just my opinion that this creates projection matrix.. To show you body of this function:

```
mat4 myW2N(float ax, float ay, float zNear, float zFar) {
    float cx = 1.0 / ax;
    float cy = 1.0 / ay;
    float z0 = -zNear;
    float z1 = -zFar;
    float az = (z0 + z1) / (z0 - z1);
    float bz = (1. - az) * z0;
    return mat4(
        cx, 0., 0., 0.,
        0., cy, 0., 0.,
        0., 0., az, bz,
        0., 0., -1., 0.
        );
    }
```

Can anybody tell me what `zNeat and zFar` represent there? I tried to put there some values and it changes shape of wraped image, but what is weird it somehow works even if `zNear` is bigger that `zFar`..

Could you give me a clue what this function means and what it does in the end, please?

Comment: "*I have an image I want to wrap around cylinder so I'm talking about orthogonal projection.*" Um, what? Are you trying to project the texture onto the cylinder? Also, are you using desktop OpenGL, OpenGL ES, or WebGL? Because they're not all the same.

Comment: Ok, I'm sorry. Yes, I want to project the texture onto the cylinder. And I'm using webGL but I thought that fragment shaders work the same everywhere..?

Comment: @NicolBolas and btw. don't you have any idea what could it be? I mean function mentioned in question..

Answer (score 2):

[You might want to read up on how matrices work](http://webglfundamentals.com) but if you follow the columns

the first column is going to multiply `X` by `1 / ax` which means it's going to scale from `+/-ax` units across to clip space `+/-1`.

The second column is going to do the same for Y scaling from `+/-ay` to clip space.

The 3rd column and 4th column effectively make the area of `zNear` to `zFar` go in Z clip space (in front of the camera) once things are divided by w. Because the 4th column is using `Z` (3rd row down), this is a perspective matrix not an orthographic matrix.

`d` is then multiplied by that matrix. The next line `vec2 p = q1.xy / q1.w`; actually makes a `p` a 2d clip space perspective coordinate. The line after `p = 0.5 * (p + 1.0)` converts from clip space 2d to texture space 2d

There's no code in your fragment related to cylinders

Comment: First thank you very much for reply. So as you said, this is perspective matrix. Does it mean that this matrix defines camera position and the scene that camera looks at is perspective?

Comment: [A projection matrix](http://webglfundamentals.org/webgl/lessons/webgl-3d-perspective.html) converts the space of some `frustum` (like a cube with one side smaller than the opposite side) to a 2 unit cube that goes +1 to -1 in each dimension. [A Camera Matrix (or View Matrix)](http://webglfundamentals.org/webgl/lessons/webgl-3d-camera.html) is what defines the camera position and orientation. Since you don't have a camera matrix your camera is at the origin looking down the -Z axis.